# get links to all sites in given domain, any tool?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, html

is it possible to get all links from given url to get all structure of given site ?

For example:

```
www.test.com
www.test.com/page1.aspx
www.test.com/page2.aspx
www.test.com/page3.aspx
www.test.com/page1.aspx?id=1
...
```

something like wget but only for retreiving links

thanks for any help

Comment: Where would these links come from?

Comment: Is spidering an option? Are you only looking for a list of pages exposed through hyperlinks or do you need to be able to get a list of all valid URLs within a domain?

Comment: @M.Babcock the best would be to get all valid urls within a domain but hyperlinks is also an option

Comment: @gruber - I don't think the page hierarchy is exposed in that way, you'll need to spider the site looking for links to pages within the domain you're searching.

Comment: If you're looking for a bot/spider/web crawler, [this discussion](http://forums.asp.net/t/1418252.aspx) contains links to several code projects.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean you want to get all the links within a page, you can use the [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) to download, parse and query the HTML for all the links it contains.

This can be extended to follow these links (keeping a list of visited links so you don't go into a loop) each at its turn and get the links on the page returned.

These are the makings of a rudimentary crawler.